# can i use h1 tag below h2 tags?

Tags: wordpress, seo

can i use h1 tag below h2 tags?
is this valid for seo?

and... can i use h2 tags in wordpress menu with this code:

```html
<a href="url"><div class="menu-one"><div class="bg"></div><h2>Text</h2></div></a>
```

```css
.menu-one {
    color: #747474;
    font-size: 10px !important;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 82px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menu-one .bg {
    background-image: url("http://.png");
    height: 34px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 82px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it good for seo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233233/is-it-good-for-seo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Typically h1...h6 are used in levels of importance, not chronology. h1 might be the heading of one article, with h2 as a sub-section. So you might have:

```
<h1>Title of Article 1</h1>
    <h2>Sub-heading</h2>
    <h2>Sub-heading</h2>
        <h3>Sub-sub-heading</h3>
<h1>Title of Article 2</h1>
    <h2>Sub-heading</h2>
    <h2>Sub-heading</h2>
```

But it's completely up to you on how you use them.

In terms of SEO, the crawlers typically assume that you are using the headers as organizational elements as well. So it will likely "see" all the items between one `<h1>` tag and another as part of one group.